# Pytest not 'updating' to new API between test scripts - FastAPI

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fastapi

I have a number of different FastAPI apps stored in one repo with file structure:

```
├── component_1/
│   ├── src/
│   │   ├── some_source.py
│   │   └── app.py
│   └── test_for_component1.py
└── component_2/
    ├── src/
    │   ├── more_source.py
    │   └── app.py
    └── test_for_component2.py
```

where `component1/src/app.py` has POST methods `/method_for_component1` and `component2/src/app.py` has POST method `/method_for_component2`.

The issue I'm having is that when I run `pytest` from the root of this directory structure it:

1. Identifies both `test_for_component1.py` and `test_for_component2.py`
2. Runs `test_for_component1.py` against `component1/src/app.py` and completes tests successfully - so far so good!
3. Starts to run `test_for_component2.py` but returns error 404 saying that `/method_for_component2` could not be found on the app... Not so good.

After some trial and error, if I include a test in `test_for_component2.py` that points towards `/method_for_component1` then I get an input error from that method (rather than a 404 - Method not found) - suggesting that between steps 2 and 3 of the above process, `pytest` is not 'updating' to look at the new `app.py`.

Why is this behaviour occurring, and what can I do to override it so that each test script effectively starts fresh with its own imports?

For context, at the start of both `test_for_component1.py` and `test_for_component2.py`, I'm using imports as follows:

For `test_for_component1.py`:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from src.app import app

def test_method_for_component1():
    response = client.post(
        "/method_for_component1",
        json={"input":"valid input"},
        headers={"content_type": "application / json"},
    )
    assert response.status_code == 200

...
```

and for `test_for_component2.py`:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from src.app import app

def test_method_for_component2():
    response = client.post(
        "/method_for_component2",
        json={"different_input":"also a valid input"},
        headers={"content_type": "application / json"},
    )
    assert response.status_code == 200

...
```

Pytest runs all tests in `test_for_component1.py` without issue, but the first test in `test_for_component2.py` returns an AssertionError where `status_code=400` rather than 200. Updating `test_for_component2.py` to:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from src.app import app

def test_method_for_component2():
    response = client.post(
        "/method_for_component1",
        json={"different_input":"also a valid input"},
        headers={"content_type": "application / json"},
    )
    assert response.status_code == 200

...
```

Returns the expected error from `/method_for_component1` for an invalid input (since `"input" != "different_input"`) - meaning that this second test script is still pointing to the first `app` object!

Any help to understand what's happening here and why would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because the import `src.app` is ambiguous, and within one `py.test` run (or more accurately, one Python interpreter lifetime) `src.app` will have been imported from either path, and won't be re-imported. (You should see that happening if you print `sys.modules['src.app']` at the start of both tests (and use `-s` to see the print.))

Furthermore, the word `src` should never appear in your import path, either; it's meant to be a plain directory that contains your app's (or apps', or libraries') sources, not a Python package.

If you insist on this "monorepo-ish" layout, then run `py.test` separately from both `component_1` and `component_2` directories. A more standard layout would be

- src/

  - component_1/

    - `__init__.py`
    - app.py
    - some_source.py
  - component_2/

    - `__init__.py`
    - app.py
    - some_source.py

with non-ambiguous imports of the `component_1.app` kind.